# How to change the checkbox, radio buttons, tab headers sizes?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Is it easy to double or triple the size of the check boxes, radio buttons, and tab headers? I have a product based on Eclipse RCP 3.4 and now running in the compatability mode on the Eclipse Mars (4.5)

Comment: I don't know of any way to change the check boxes and radio buttons.

Comment: AFAIK, check boxes & radio buttons sizes are controlled by the underlying UI implementation.

Comment: so only one way is to create a custom widget with similar behaviour and required size, right?